# How do I use collection class inside react?

Tags: reactjs

So, I want to use collection class inside react I tried the following way

```
    class Collect extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {

      }

  };


  render() {
     return (
            <div class="collection">
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item">Name
            <span class="badge"> 3 </span></a>
            </div>
           );
         }
```

}

It did not work in the expected materializecss way. What would have gone wrong?
Or is this an issue with materializecss on react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `className` instead of `class`. Like:

```
return (
    <div className="collection">
        <a href="#!" className="collection-item">Name
            <span className="badge"> 3 </span></a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Look [`HTML Attributes`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-attributes) documentation.